# How to use prepared statements with Inner join queries in SQL Php?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, subquery

I have some queries with inner joins and I have some give attributes such as this case:

```
...INNER JOIN users ON ? = users.id
                WHERE report_cases_accepted.report_id=?
```

now the question is, is it correct if I put that "?" after `ON`?

Comment: I'd expect a column from the other table in the ON clause.

Comment: Prepared statements accept only values as parameters hence you cannot represent a column name with `?` mark

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wasn't using prepared statements before so I was doing it like this `INNER JOIN users ON '$device_manufacturer' = users.id` and it returns what it should, so why is it working like this then?

Comment: wait. you cannot join a table on a condition that doesn't belong to that table. Something wrong with your join. You better ask another question about your SQL query

Comment: Are you trying to use a *value* in that first placeholder?  If so, that sounds like a misuse of a `JOIN` that should be part of a `WHERE`.  Or are you trying to dynamically use a *column* in that placeholder, such as having multiple columns in your table which have FK to `users`?  There could be a variety of solutions to that logic, and the table design may be wrong to begin with.  You *can* safely concatenate strings for that purpose, as long as those strings are **not** user-editable.  For example, an array of known values in the code from which you select one based on your logic.

Comment: @David this variable `$device_manufacturer` has an id of a user, but how can I use in the Where clause since I dont know how to then join users table

Comment: @ttt: We don't know, since we know nothing of your table structure or what your query is attempting to select from that structure.  But joining is done on *columns*, not on *values*.